# IXAudio2->CreateSoundVoice returns with error

Tags: c++, winapi, xaudio2

I'm trying to make simple sound buffer and play it using XAudio 2.

First i have initialized the IXAudio2

```cpp
IXAudio2* XAudio = 0;
int XAudioInitFailed = XAudio2Create(&XAudio, 0, XAUDIO2_DEFAULT_PROCESSOR);

//check for failure

IXAudio2MasteringVoice* MasterVoice = 0;
XAudio->CreateMasteringVoice(&MasterVoice);
```

Next I populate my data.

```cpp
// Mono 8-bit 44.1kHz PCM format
WAVEFORMATEX WaveFormat = {};
WaveFormat.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
WaveFormat.nChannels = 1;
WaveFormat.nSamplesPerSec = 44100;
WaveFormat.wBitsPerSample = 8;
WaveFormat.nBlockAlign = WaveFormat.nChannels * WaveFormat.wBitsPerSample / 8;
WaveFormat.nAvgBytesPerSec = WaveFormat.nSamplesPerSec * WaveFormat.nBlockAlign;
WaveFormat.cbSize = sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX);

// Populating my SoundBuffer
// Creating XAudio sound buffer struct

IXAudio2SourceVoice* SourceVoice = 0;
int code = XAudio->CreateSourceVoice(&SourceVoice, &WaveFormat);
SourceVoice->SubmitSourceBuffer(&XBuffer); //this line triggers exceptions
SourceVoice->Start(0);
```

And when i run the code, exception is triggered on the line `SourceVoice->SubmitSourceBuffer(&XBuffer);`, code is `0x88960001` which means `XAUDIO2_E_INVALID_CALL` according to Microsoft windows API page.

Help me figure out what the problem might have been.

**UPDATE**: Full code:

```cpp
WinAudio = {};
    IXAudio2* XAudio = 0;
    int XAudioInitFailed = XAudio2Create(&XAudio, 0, XAUDIO2_DEFAULT_PROCESSOR);
    if(!XAudioInitFailed) {

        //NOTE: creating the mastering voice
        IXAudio2MasteringVoice* MasterVoice = 0;
        XAudio->CreateMasteringVoice(&MasterVoice);

        //NOTE: initializing PlayBuffer
        // Mono 8-bit 44.1kHz PCM format
        WAVEFORMATEX WaveFormat = {};
        WaveFormat.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
        WaveFormat.nChannels = 1;
        WaveFormat.nSamplesPerSec = 44100;
        WaveFormat.wBitsPerSample = 8;
        WaveFormat.nBlockAlign = WaveFormat.nChannels * WaveFormat.wBitsPerSample / 8;
        WaveFormat.nAvgBytesPerSec = WaveFormat.nSamplesPerSec * WaveFormat.nBlockAlign;
        WaveFormat.cbSize = sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX);

        // NOTE: initializing SoundBuffer
        int SampleFrequency = 256;
        int Samples = WaveFormat.nSamplesPerSec;
        int AudioBytes = Samples * WaveFormat.nBlockAlign;
        i1* SoundBuffer = (i1*)malloc(AudioBytes);
        i1* WritePointer = SoundBuffer;
        for(int Sample = 0;
            Sample < Samples;
            Sample ++) {
            i1 value = ((Sample / SampleFrequency)%2)*10;

            *WritePointer++ = value;
            //*WritePointer++ = value;
        }

        // NOTE: Creating Sound
        XAUDIO2_BUFFER XBuffer = {};
        XBuffer.Flags = XAUDIO2_END_OF_STREAM;
        XBuffer.AudioBytes = AudioBytes;
        XBuffer.pAudioData = (const BYTE*)SoundBuffer;
        // NOTE: The following parameters are
        // measured in samples
        XBuffer.PlayBegin = 0;
        XBuffer.PlayLength = 0; 
        XBuffer.LoopBegin = 0;
        XBuffer.LoopLength = 0;
        XBuffer.LoopCount = XAUDIO2_LOOP_INFINITE;

        IXAudio2SourceVoice* SourceVoice = 0;
        int code = XAudio->CreateSourceVoice(&SourceVoice, &WaveFormat);
        SourceVoice->SubmitSourceBuffer(&XBuffer);
        SourceVoice->Start(0);
    } else {
        // TODO: Diagnose
        InvalidCodePath;
    }
```

Comment: Your title says `CreateSoundVoice()` is returning an error, but your question is taking about a crash in `SubmitSourceBuffer()`. Where is your error checking for `CreateSourceVoice()` before calling `SubmitSourceBuffer()`? Is `SourceVoice` a valid pointer? How are you populating the `XBuffer`? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: ``int code`` doesn't look like correct ``HRESULT`` checking. That's the first place to start: Make sure to use ``HRESULT``, ``SUCCEEDED``, and ``FAILED`` macros.  Also take a look at the [XAudio2 samples](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/tree/master/XAudio2).

Comment: There are two possibilities, 1)  Your `WAVEFORMATEX` structure is corrupt and contains incorrect or uninitialized data. 2) You are running out of available voice channels due to a channel leak somewhere in your code.

Comment: I have added the complete code that i run. Don't mind the WinAudio struct i dont use it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the error for `CreateMasterVoice`, if it failed, `CreateSourceVoice` will fail also. 
The error `XAUDIO2_E_INVALID_CALL` makes me think that `CreateMasterVoice` was not successful.

The error from `CreateMasterVoice` will gives you more hint about the issue. 
For instance, you might have forgotten to call `CoInitialize` before creating XAudio2, in this case `CreateMasterVoice` fails with `CO_E_NOTINITIALIZED`.